# inflater.inflate() ,menu cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, menu, inflate

I'm using `inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);`,But this line have this error:

```
menu cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

I'm using above function in this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;

    // Inflate the currently selected menu XML resource.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

I have `menu.xml` in `/res/menu` folder, and it's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_help"
        android:title="@string/help"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:title="@string/about"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_support"
        android:title="@string/support"/>

</menu>
```

And ,in `R.java` R.menu is defined:

```
public static final class menu {
        public static final int menu=0x7f080000;
        public static final int title_only=0x7f080001;
    }
```

I see some duplicate question in Stackoverflow, but any answer can't help me to solve this problem

please help me to solve this problem

Thanks

=======================

Thanks to all of friends,all things seems correct, But there was still a problem
I close Eclipse completely and restart my laptop,after restart when open the Eclipse and run my application, it work correctly and with no error.
I don't understood really what's the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [menu cannot be resolved or is not a field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413746/menu-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field)

Comment: Make sure you don't have android.R in your imports.

Comment: what is your second parameter `menu` ?

Comment: @Egor, i checked the imports, and don't see android.R

Comment: @njzk2,i add the complete method that i use it, in the above post

Comment: @J.Romero, i see some duplicate question in stackoverflow, but any answer can't help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

I think you are imported android.R file that's why its giving like that..
check your imported statements and import your package R.java file..

Comment: I think R.java work correctly because in the on create override,i use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and it's have not error

Comment: I had similar problem and issue was with the wrong import. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have instantiated the wrong R.menu. you had probably taken the R.menu (from the android sdk)

Comment: In eclipse: Type "R" -> [CNTR]+[SPACE] -> Choice YOUR instance of "R"

Comment: When i add `import android.R;`, this line:`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` get same error (`menu cannot be resolved or is not a field`)

Comment: you should not import android.R
You have to import your own R

Comment: Are you mean this? :`import com.example.myproject.R;`

Comment: yes, if "com.example.myproject.*" is your package

Comment: I test it but have no effect on error